# Appengine Appstats: My RPC calls total 8s but my grand total is 30s. Why?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, profiling

I am learning to profile my app on appengine. I don't understand how my RPC total could be 8 seconds while the grand total of view is longer around 30 seconds?

Other sources of delay could arise from:

1. Template rendering
2. Computational time

Does appengine have other tools to let me dig deeper?

If this helps:

```
@app.route('/orders/schedule/all/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def generate_schedule_for_all_orders():
  """Merge all the orders together in one big schedule

  TODO: put range by default.
  TODO: think of default empty scenario
  """
  orders = key_dict(Order.query().fetch())

  # TODO: somehow there's a lot of orphaned tasks in development. For now,
  # we will just query for non orphaned tasks to prevent errors piling up
  tasks = Task.query(Task.order.IN(orders.keys())).order(Task.action).fetch()

  ds = sorted([t.date for t in tasks])
  start, end = ds[0], ds[-1]
  dates = range_for_dates(start, end)

  return render_template('backward_schedule.html',
                         tasks=tasks,
                         orders=orders,
                         producetypes=key_dict(ProduceType.query().fetch()),
                         dates=dates,
                         display_order_info=True)
```

And this is the template macro:

```
{% macro generate_calendar(tasks, orders, producetypes, dates, display_order_info) %}
<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'>
  <tr>
    <th class='weekends'>Sunday</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
  </tr>

  {# start is always on a Sunday while end is always on a saturday #}

  {% for week in dates %}
    <tr>
      <td class='weekends'>{{ _display_day(week[0], tasks, orders, display_order_info) }}</td>
      <td>{{ _display_day(week[1], tasks, orders, display_order_info) }}</td>
      <td>{{ _display_day(week[2], tasks, orders, display_order_info) }}</td>
      <td>{{ _display_day(week[3], tasks, orders, display_order_info) }}</td>
      <td>{{ _display_day(week[4], tasks, orders, display_order_info) }}</td>
      <td>{{ _display_day(week[5], tasks, orders, display_order_info) }}</td>
      <td class='weekends'>{{ _display_day(week[6], tasks, orders, display_order_info) }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}

</table>
{% endmacro %}


{% macro _display_day(a_date, tasks, orders, display_order_info) %}
  {% if a_date.day == 1 %}
    <div class='date'>{{ a_date.strftime('%B') }} {{ a_date.day }}</div>
  {% else %}
    <div class='date'>{{ a_date.day }}</div>
  {% endif %}

  <ul class='list-group'>
    {% for task in tasks %}
      {% set order = orders[task.order] %}
      {% set order_entry = order.get_entry(task.order_entry_serial) %}

      {% if task.date == a_date %}
        <li class='list-group-item'>
          {% if display_order_info %}
            <a href="{{ url_for('view_order', order_id=task.order.id()) }}">
              {{ order.name }}
            </a>
          {% endif %}
          <span>{{ order_entry.quantity }}</span>
          <span>{{ producetypes[order_entry.producetype].name() }}</span>
          <span>{{ task.action }}</span>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endmacro %}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: A few things you should look at.  Firstly remove all the calendar generating code, and re-run with appstats to see if that is what is taking up the time.  Check the logs to see if this request is also a startup request.

Comment: @TimHoffman I tried using memcache to see if it will improve the rendering but I am running into problems ;(

Comment: But you are only using memcache to save some db time. Memcache can't speed up rendering onlyu access to the data that is rendered.  If your HTML generation is slow no amount of memcache will make that faster unless you cache the HTML.  Find out first though where the time is being taken up, and use a larger explicit batch size on your queries.  Default batch is 20

Comment: @TimHoffman I took your advice and profile with and without calendar generation: it's a stunning difference of 6900ms vs 39711ms. I am gonna start investigating on jinja generation is taking so long. Thanks!

Comment: Though 6900ms is also very long, look at batch sizes on your queries , they may help

Comment: 6900ms without memcache working (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174153/appengine-memcache-expiring-really-quickly)

Comment: Yes, but you do quite a few RPCs,  it can improve total to e by reducing the number, and its just an argument supplied to the query.  It is worth having a look.  I saw your other memcache post, and I haven't got my head around what you are doing there yet.